# Postgres live query event on postgres queries

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Is it possible to use something like `SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity` with a live query such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-live-select?

I've tried to run this, but I get `error: permission denied: "pg_authid" is a system catalog`.

It would be to basically get an event where I can check the query running whenever Postgres is queried.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity` is query like every other so it's possible to use it with any library as long as you are connected as database superuser (and that's the problem in your case).

Comment: I am the pg sql superuser/root user